# Looking for New Ideas on An Old Interview Trick

Tags: algorithm, random, probability

The original question is:

Describe an algorithm to output a die roll(a random number from 1 to 6), given a function that outputs a coin toss(a random number from 1 to 2). Each possible outcome should be equally likely.

The most popular answer to this question is:

Flip the coin three times, and use the three coin flips as the bits of a three-bit number. If the number is in the range 1 to 6, output the number. Otherwise, repeat.

My question is:

Most of the discussions on Stack Overflow come in the above flavour. I've also searched the Internet, finding that there exist many answers of other flavours, which they don't explicitly dig into. Could someone please share one or two different ideas on this problem?

Comment: There's quite a fundamental level at which the problem is about expressing six things using sequences of 2 different symbols. So how do you define "flavour"? The two most common ways of doing it are this one (only use 6 out of the 8 possible 3-sequences), and the one based on expressing sixths as (non-terminating) binary fractions. Do they have different flavours, or not?

Comment: Is it part of [Ponder this](http://domino.research.ibm.com/Comm/wwwr_ponder.nsf/Challenges/September2011.html) problem from last month? :-)

Comment: It's BS that this got closed.  It's clearly a question about a software algorithm and hence on topic.

Comment: @KeithIrwin: I assume the problem is that the question was asking for an alternative algorithm for one that is widely believed to be the best one possible for this situation. It just seemed a bit vague to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want other options, not necessarily good ones then how about this:

1. Flip a coin for each possible output value.
2. If there is one or more heads then discard all the possible values that got tails.
3. If you have only one value left then stop. Else goto 1.

I would suspect it is going to have a higher expected number of coin tosses than the method you've described and have no advantages at all really.

In general I assume this is why there is not much on the other possible ways of using random numbers. They are just not as good.

Answer (score 3):

There is a small improvement to the "toss 3 times and discard if 110 or 111" algorithm. Discarding 110 or 111 is wasteful, since you are wasting  one perfectly good bit of entropy that you could reuse. After one of these values pops up, you only need to toss twice and get the value of the third toss from the mapping {110->tails, 111->heads}. Both of 110 and 111 are equally probable, so  you're not introducing any bias this way.

In pseudocode:

```
bit0 = toss()
while True:
   bit1 = toss()
   bit2 = toss()
   if bit1,bit2,bit3 give i such that 0<=i<=5 then 
      return i+1
   else
      bit0 = bit3 // the reuse happens here
```

The expected number of tosses here is 1 + 2 * expected_number_of_loop_executions = 1+2*8/6 = 11/3

Comment: In original case average coin toss is 4. In this improved case it's 11/3≈3.67

Comment: @Dialecticus: Thanks, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Or you could express it `do { bit0 = toss(); bit1 = toss(); } while (bit0 and bit1); bit2 = toss(); return 1 + bit2 + 2*bit1 + 4*bit0;`. Should be the same expected number of tosses, but avoids the slightly confusing re-use of a bit.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I believe this could be treated as a different idea, namely emulation of a 3-sided die, followed by a separate coin toss. This warrants a separate answer, IMHO.

Comment: @RafałDowgird: I actually conceived it just by noting that you would discard a 3-bit result if and only if the first two bits are 1, hence we can decide to do that without wasting time generating that third bit. But with a slightly different `return` statement, yes, my code would be obviously equivalent to `d3() + 3 * toss()`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: It's rather d3() * 2 + toss(), but of course d3() + 4 * toss() is almost the same. (Assuming zero-based dice results)

Answer (score 1):

1. Flip 5 coins.  If they're all heads or all tails, your answer is 1.  If there's only one head or one tail, continue to the next step.  If there's more than one head and more than one tail, repeat this step (including reflipping the coins).
2. Flip 4 coins.  If they're all heads or all tails, your answer is 2.  If there's only one head or one tail, continue to the next step.  If there's two heads and two tails, repeat this step (including reflipping the coins).
3. Flip 3 coins.  If they're all heads or all tails, your answer is 3.  Otherwise, continue to the next step
4. Flip 2 coins.  If they're both heads, your answer is 4.  If they're both tails, repeat this step (including reflipping the coins).  Otherwise, continue to the next step.
5. Flip 1 coin.  If it's heads, your answer is 5.  If it's tails, your answer is 6.

Comment: And this gives the questioner exactly what they deserve for asking for alternative answers. It's less efficient than the answer we're supposed to avoid, *and* harder to prove correct. Excellent :-)

Comment: Hang on, though. I see that given we reach step 3, the conditional probability of getting answer 3 is 1/4, which is correct. But given we reach step 4, the conditional probability of getting answer 4 is 1/2, with a 1/2 chance of moving on to step 5. That seems wrong, shouldn't it be 1/3 chance of answer 4, 2/3 moving on? That is, there should be a 1/4 chance of repeating step 4.

Comment: @Steve: You're right.  I miscalculated.  I got into my pattern and missed that I had to change it for the 1 2 1 case.  It's fixed now.